# Enterprise or Self-Service API - Request suggestion

Tags: api, amadeus

I'm in the process of devolving a new tool for a company app. The tool will be sending homogeneous number of searches to amadeus API. Is every search result is considered as a request? A sample search of a user will have to search the api 1000 times are these searches considered as requests? Because if the company has 10000 request limit per month it's going to be over by 10 users! I need to understand this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call an API (every time you use GET/POST verb) you do a "request".

The limitation (quota) is only in the test environment, you don't pay for it but you have a limited number of calls and you only have access to a subset of data.

In production, you don't have any limitation on the total number of queries you can do. You get access to our full set of data (live) but you pay per use (you pay for each request you do).

You have a limitation on the number you can do per second (TPS: 10 in production / 5 in test).